# A good Lua editor for Mac?

Tags: text, ide, editor, lua

Whats a good Lua text editor for the Mac? All I need is just to edit the code. Not a Compiler or anything.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/143939/whats-a-good-ide-to-use-for-lua

Comment: Try [ZeroBrane Studio Lua IDE](http://studio.zerobrane.com/): syntax highlighting, auto-complete, static analysis, and more (details in this [SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10938831/1442917)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BBEdit is the best all-around editor for the Mac. Lua is one of the default languages for the syntax colorizer.

Comment: And TextWrangler is a free (stripped-down but fully functional) version of BBEdit.

Comment: Also see [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/) which is open source btw. Emacs for Mac:) Pretty much feature rich as BBEdit

Comment: BBEdit's indentation functionality is not good~ Go with Sublime text 2.

Answer (score 2):

Any number of editors will work fine. I use Vim (But if you're on a mac you might want to use MacVim instead). TextMate is also a good mac editor. Just about any editor that can display monospaced fonts and do syntax highlighting should be sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

If you know [MacVim](http://code.google.com/p/macvim/) or [Vim](http://www.vim.org/download.php#mac) use it! Vim has builtin [Lua syntax support](ftp://ftp.vim.org/pub/vim/runtime/syntax/lua.vim).
If you don't know, learn it ;)

Otherwise use TextMate with the enhanced lua bundle ([demo video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O4YLoa1NC48), [project site](https://github.com/BlackBulletIV/enhanced-lua.tmbundle))

Answer (score 0):

There's also eclipse which is a nice all purpose java based IDE with many different language specific perspectives, including one for lua http://luaeclipse.luaforge.net/